# 'module' object is not callable when masking dataframe by datetime

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I try to remove some dates from my dataframe, however I get this TypeError. Datetime is being importet at the top.

`merge_fra = merge_fra[(merge_fra.index < datetime(year=2019, day=4, month=3))&(merge_fra.index > datetime(year=2019, day=12, month=3))]`

[image]

EDIT:
datetime.datetime solves it.
However, I get an empty dataframe:
[image]

Comment: use `datetime.datetime` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the datetime import but I guess it's like this:

`import datetime`

so, you have either to import datetime as:

`from datetime import datetime`

or use `datetime.datetime()` in your code, because at the moment you are trying to call the `datetime` module instead of the class

Comment: Thank you! However, that gives me an empy dataframe merge_fra. It's another question, but do you know why it could be empty?